# Send Email if Hangfire Recurring Job isn't triggered

Tags: .net, hangfire, .net-framework-version

I have an API that's built on .Net Framework 4.7 and uses Hangfire to run some recurring Jobs. I need to know if there is a way to send out an Email if the Recurring Job isn't triggered at the specific time based on the Cron expression. i did try to find from the Hangfire documentation but couldn't find any. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the scenarios where a job wouldn't get triggered on a set time ?

Comment: That's what i am not sure but i have seen the Recurring Jobs aren't getting triggered intermittently so was looking for a way to receive an email when this happens.